# Vermeiden von Personalpronomen für Gegenstände

Tags: pronoun, speaking

Ich höre manchmal Sätze wie z. B.:

> Die Uhr ist alt, *die* habe ich von meinem Opa.
>   Der Zug ist verspätet, *der* geht aber bald.

Sollte es wohl nicht eigentlich *sie* bzw. *er* heißen? Warum macht man diesen "Fehler"? Trifft dies auch bei sächlichen Substantiven zu (*es*/*das*)?

Comment: Woa. "Die Uhr ist alt, sie habe ich von meinem Opa." klingt ganz furchtbar schräg. Würd ich im Traum nie sagen. Und ein Zug geht nicht, er fährt. Kann es sein, dass bei dir ein Dialekt das Hochdeutsche verwirrt?

Comment: @ what: Die Sätze habe ich selbst konstruiert und sie klingen wahrsceinlich komisch, weil ich nicht Deutsch als Muttersprache habe. Darum geht die Frage aber nicht, sondern um das Austauschen von persönlichen Pronomina zu den bestimmten Artikeln

Comment: @beta "Die" und "der" werden hier nicht als Artikel benutzt, sondern als Demonstrativpronomen. Siehe Antwort von Matthias.

Comment: @what »Der Zug geht um halb fünf« ist für mich völlig in Ordnung …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es handelt sich hierbei um ein umgangssprachliches Phänomen. Deine Sätze könnten genauso gut heißen:

> Die Uhr ist alt, ich habe *sie* von meinem Opa.
>
> Der Zug ist verspätet, *er* fährt aber bald.

Also: **beide Varianten sind korrekt**, deine ist mehr umgangssprachlich. Diese Tendenz lässt sich auch bei Personen beobachten:

> Die Jasmin, die ist aber echt eine Nette.
>
> *(Reaktion auf einen schlechten Autofahrer)*: Wo fährt der denn lang?!

Die Kombination *es/das* ist schwierig. Rein theoretisch könnte es sich damit genauso verhalten wie mit *er/sie*. Doch die Sprache ist nun mal nicht logisch - *das* bezieht sich oft auf *eine Sache*, *etwas* und hat sprachlich einen anderen Charakter.

> Das *[=das Baby]* ist im Garten und spielt.

Der obige Satz klingt etwas seltsam. Wahrscheinlich wegen Konnotationen zu einer solchen Nutzung:

> Wo fand die Vorstellung letzte Woche statt?
>
> Es/Das war im Stadtpark, glaube ich.

Hier bezieht sich das Wort *das* auf nichts vom neutralen Geschlecht, sondern auf die Vorstellung. Daher wäre der Babysatz einzig und alleine so richtig:

> Wo ist das Baby?
>
> Es ist im Garten und spielt.

Dahingegen allgemeine, subjektlose Sätze wie:

> Es gilt, dass...
>
> Es regnet.
>
> Es gibt...

oder Inversionen wie

> Es passieren manchmal noch Wunder.

funktionieren *nur* mit *es*, weil das *es* eben keinen Gegenstand und keine Person bezeichnet, sondern es erfüllt eine rein grammatikalische Funktion.

Comment: _Das Baby, das spielt im Garten._ und _Wo ist das Baby? [Das] spielt im Garten._ sind mündlich völlig akzeptabel und gebräuchlich. Allerdings würde ich in _Das Baby [das] ist im Garten, **das** spielt._ auch _es_ erwarten. Das Neutrum ist halt eher ein Objektgenus.

Comment: »Das Buch ist selten.« »Das habe ich auf einem Flohmarkt entdeckt.« Meines Erachtens kein Problem.

Comment: @Jan weil Buch ein Gegenstand ist, ein Baby aber nicht.

Comment: Oh, ich habe auch mit einem Baby als Zielwort von *das* kein Problem. Auch nicht mit einem Madl, zumal ich enge Bindungen nach Rheinhessen habe, wo man üblicherweise von *es Lara* (das Lara) spricht.

Answer (score 5):

Die Sätze sind korrekt. Die beiden Wörter nach den Kommas sind hier keine bestimmten Artikel, auch wenn sie erst mal so aussehen, sondern Demonstrativpronomen. [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-der-die-das.html) hat eine ganz gute Seite dazu.

Der Unterschied zwischen

> Die Uhr ist alt, die habe ich von meinem Opa.

und

> Die Uhr ist alt, ich habe sie von meinem Opa.

besteht also in der Nuance, dass im ersten Fall der zweite Teilsatz nochmal auf die Uhr hinweist, sie also etwas stärker betont.

Das [sic!] geht auch mit sächlichen Nomen:

> Das Buch ist neu, das habe ich zum Geburtstag bekommen!

Answer (score 3):

Die beiden Sätze sind verschieden. Im ersten Beispiel wechselt das Subjekt (von "Uhr" zu "ich"). Im zweiten Beispiel bleibt der Zug das Subjekt.

#### Schauen wir uns erstmal das zweite Beispiel an:

> Der Zug ist verspätet, der [fährt] aber bald.

Hier kann man das Pronomen auch weglassen, was etwas eleganter klingt:

> Der Zug ist verspätet, fährt aber bald.

Oder man fügt einen Punkt ein, weil der Sprecher eine Pause macht:

> Der Zug ist verspätet. *(Pause)* Er fährt aber bald.

In dem Fall klingt das Personalpronomen besser als das Demonstrativpronomen. Also verbessern wir das zweite Beispiel zu:

> Der Zug ist verspätet, er fährt aber bald.

Mit "der" ist es nicht falsch, aber mit "er" klingts natürlicher.

#### Schauen wir uns jetzt das erste Beispiel an:

> Die Uhr ist alt, die habe ich von meinem Opa.

Wenn man hier das Pronomen weglassen will, muss man den zweiten Satz umstellen:

> * Die Uhr ist alt, habe ich von meinem Opa.

geht nicht, aber das hier geht:

> Die Uhr ist alt, ich habe sie von meinem Opa.

Aber diese beiden Sätze würde man so nicht ohne wenigstens eine kurze Pause sprechen, also ist ein Punkt zwischen den Sätzen vielleicht ein klein wenig besser als ein Komma:

> Die Uhr ist alt. *(Pause)* Ich habe sie von meinem Opa.

Wenn man einen Punkt setzt, muss man den zweiten Satz aber nicht umstellen:

> Die Uhr ist alt. *(Pause)* Hab ich von meinem Opa.

Das ist sehr an der gesprochenen Sprache orientiert, deshalb habe ich auch "habe" zu "hab" verkürzt.

Alle Varianten ohne "*" kann man verwenden. Welche besser ist, kommt darauf an, in welchem Kontext sie verwendet wird.

Comment: *Die Uhr ist alt, habe ich von meinem Opa.*  wäre umgangsprachlich vollkommen in Ordnung, aber niederschreiben sollte man es nicht. Das Subjekt ist nur implizit vorhanden (weil es im vorigen Satz erwähnt wird oder in der Situation gerade jemand darauf zeigt,..). Sind eben informell.

Comment: @Chieron Wie ich in meiner Antwort argumentiere, ist da mindestens eine winzige Pause zwischen den beiden Sätzen. Deshalb, denke ich, ist da ein Punkt besser als ein Komma. Wenn man keine Pause macht, klingt es wie `"Die Uhr ist alt" habe ich von meinem Opa.`, d.h. den Satz "Die Uhr ist alt" hat der Sprecher von seinem Opa. Sprich es einfach mal laut vor dich hin ...

Comment: Ich würde den Satz eher mit einem Gedankenstrich wiedergeben, statt eine Ellipse nachzuschieben. Und Kommata können Pausen recht variabler Länge bedeuten. Falls es eine echte Unterhaltung wiedergeben soll, wird der Kontext ebenfalls dafür sorgen, dass der Leser nicht den Eindruck eines Maschinengewehrs als Sprecher hat.

Comment: Nicht "Relativpronomen", sondern **Demonstrativpronomen**.

Comment: @what Dass 'der/die/das' _auch_ als Relativpronomen verwendet werden können, heißt nicht, dass es sich in den Sätzen hier um Relativpronomen handelt. Grammatischer Unterschied: Ein Relativpronomen würde einen Relativsatz einleiten, und ein Relativsatz hat immer den Satzbau eines Nebensatzes (dependent/subordinate clause) mit _Verbletztstellung_, d.h., das finite Verb wird ans Ende gestellt. Die Satzbeispiele hier haben dagegen die Wortstellung von  Hauptsätzen (independent/main clause) mit Verbzweitstellung.

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous Da hast du recht. Hab's verbessert.

Comment: Das Komma kann auch als Aufzählung gedeutet werden, dabei ist aber problematisch, dass die Uhr erst grammatisches Subjekt dann Objekt wäre. Dennoch bleibt die Uhr Thema des Satzes und darauf kommt es an. Man könnte genauso gut fragen, ob ein oder zwei *das* nötig wäre(n) in "[Das] Was dir fehlt, [das] habe ich von meinem Opa". Ist eher unüblich, denke ich.